# MMDrawerController unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cocoa

I'm trying to setup a siderbar navigation menu for my app. I'm using the MMDrawerController lib, but I'm running into an issue. I've added a button and use these methods to call the sidebar:

```
-(void)setupLeftMenuButton{
    MMDrawerBarButtonItem * leftDrawerButton = [[MMDrawerBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftDrawerButtonPress:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftDrawerButton animated:YES];
}

-(void)leftDrawerButtonPress:(id)sender{
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm using a Navigation Controller with a View Controller attached in which I'm calling this method. This viewcontroller is called ViewController2.

Whenever I press the button to pull out the sidemenu, it crashes and returns this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController2 mm_drawerController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x835b440'

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MMDrawerController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "MMLeftSideDrawerViewController.h"
#import "MMRightSideDrawerViewController.h"
#import "MMDrawerVisualState.h"
#import "MMDrawerVisualStateManager.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) MMDrawerController * drawerController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    UIViewController * leftSideDrawerViewController = [[MMLeftSideDrawerViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController * centerViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc] init]; // MAYBE SOMETHING WRONG HERE?

    UIViewController * rightSideDrawerViewController = [[MMRightSideDrawerViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];
    [navigationController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMCenterNavigationControllerRestorationKey"];

    self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                             initWithCenterViewController:navigationController
                             leftDrawerViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController
                             rightDrawerViewController:rightSideDrawerViewController];
    [self.drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];
    [self.drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:200.0];
    [self.drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
    [self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];

    [self.drawerController
     setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
         MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock block;
         block = [[MMDrawerVisualStateManager sharedManager]
                  drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:drawerSide];
         if(block){
             block(drawerController, drawerSide, percentVisible);
         }
     }];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder{
    return YES;
}


- (UIViewController *)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSString * key = [identifierComponents lastObject];
    if([key isEqualToString:@"MMDrawer"]){
        return self.window.rootViewController;
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"MMCenterNavigationControllerRestorationKey"]) {
        return ((MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController).centerViewController;
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"MMLeftSideDrawerController"]){
        return ((MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController).leftDrawerViewController;
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"MMRightSideDrawerController"]){
        return ((MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController).rightDrawerViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: How can you setup root MMDrawer VC?

Comment: It is explained here: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController
But I haven't done that yet..

Comment: Investigate AppDelegate.m in sample code and setup root MMDrawer for your VC

Comment: It keeps throwing me exceptions. I'm created all the files as in the example and replaced centerViewController with ViewController2.
But it now crashes right after building the app. I first have a ViewController, and then it should go to VC2. What do you mean with setting up a root MMDrawer?

Comment: Show your code in AppDelegate

Comment: Added it to my post. The error I'm getting has to do with the Left and Right side drawers. Cause if I comment them out, it crashes only after clicking the drawer button.

[MMLeftSideDrawerViewController mm_visibleDrawerFrame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8293f60'

Comment: Ok since I have a rather strange hierarchy in my app, I guess some I need a different approach. Let me once again elaborate on how my app looks: When the app opens, it shows VC1, which was mostly designed in IB. I do not call it in AppDelegate, so I don't even know why it shows up first. After logging in, it pushes to an instance on VC2, which has an upper laying Navigation Controller. In this VC2 I want to implement the sidemenu. Would I have to move the code from AppDelegate to the viewDidLoad of VC2? Despite my messyness, I still like to figure this out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example have you tried something like in case you are using navigation

(or swapping view in case you are not)

[(UINavigationController*)self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController pushViewController: animated:YES];